# Considerate, dynamic CPU load management

Tags: multithreading, multicore, cpu-usage

I am writing a CPU-intensive image processing library. To make best use of available CPU, I can detect the total number of cores on my machine and have my library run with that number of threads. When my library to allocate one thread for each core it performs optimally using 100% available processor time.

The above approach works fine when mine is the only CPU-heavy process running.  If another CPU-intensive process is running, or even another instance of my own code, then the OS allocates us only a fraction of the available cores and my library then has too many threads running which is both inefficient and inconsiderate to other processes.

So I would like to find a way to determine the "fair share" number of threads to run given a specific load.  For example, if two instances of my process are running on an 8-core machine, each would run with 4 threads.  Each would need a way to adapt thread count dynamically according to fluctuations in machine load.

So, my question:

- Is there any OS feature or third-party library which allows my process to adapt thread count dynamically to use its fair share of the CPU?

My focus is Windows but interested in non-Windows solutions too.

*Edit: to be clear, this is about optimization.  I am trying to achieve peak efficiency by running the optimal number of threads appropriate to my fair share of the CPU.*

Comment: 'If another CPU-intensive process is running, or even another instance of my own code, then the OS allocates us only a fraction of the available cores'.  Why is this happening?  This is unnnatural behaviour for multithreaded apps that are CPU-bound.  It sounds more like your box is disk-bound under these conditions, ie. there is a lot of page-fault or other disk holdups that cuts the number of ready threads down to less than the number of cores.

Comment: Disk/IO is not an issue.  Pure number crunching here.  You have two identical CPU-bound processes - both get half available CPU, that's fair.  But this is suboptimal for both - they are running two threads per available core.  Inefficiency comes from context switching/synchronization overhead.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is the job of the operating system.  If you limit yourself to 4 threads then your program takes twice as long.  Just starting 8, if the user starts another process that also starts 8 threads then your program *still* takes twice as long.  The context switches are a very small part of the execution time.  You cannot find out what else is burning core anyway.

Comment: Threads are tightly synchronized using lightweight spinlocks.  This is the only parallelization paradigm that works for my application and it's blazingly fast when cores are free.  In the extreme case, if I am running 8 threads but only getting utilization of 1 core then my threads are effectively serialized and taking turns to run.  In this case, I get much lower throughput than if I ran just a single thread.  On context switches - yes this is small but L1/L2 cache data gets trashed and has to be re-fetched when thread gets focus again.

Comment: Ahh.. spinlocks.  All is revealed :((

Comment: Put a configurable cap on the spins, then fall back to a kernel lock so that the other thread - the one that holds the lock and is just one instruction from releasing it - gets to run, else you will probably burn up the one core for 30ms on the spinner, as you already realise, (or realize for US posters:).  It sounds like you have a lot of contention in your app - spinners are fine when the chance of contention is very low, eg. pushing/popping an instance variable on/from a queue, but get painful if the lock is regularly held for extended periods.

Comment: Chance of contention is very low providing that each thread runs continuously.  If one is switched out of context then very quickly the others halt, waiting for it.  A circular dependency exists between the threads.

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes, the application shouldnt decide how many threads to spawn. This is an information, that the caller should know. In linux, the "-j" or "--jobs" parameter is widely used (Default: 1).

What about also setting the **priority** of the processing tasks. So if the caller knows, the processing is mission-critical, he can increase the prio (with the knowledge of maybe blocking the (whole) system). Your processing lib would never know, how important the processing of *this* image would be.
If the caller doesnt care, then the default low-prio is used, which *shouldnt* affect the rest of the system. If it does, you should look to what is exactly blocking the system (maybe writing image files to the hdd, reduce ram size to prevent swapping, ...). If you figured out that, you can optimize exactly that point.

If you start the processing with (cpu-cores)*2 on low till normal priority, your system should be useable. No one would expect, that this will kill the system.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Good point on priority. If the PC is supposed to be responsive to the user input while processing something for a long time, priority and I/O priority have to be considered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but priority is not an issue.  Achieving one thread per available core is my goal - this gives peak efficiency.  Easy when machine otherwise idle, more difficult when others are sharing CPU.

Comment: I thunk he's saying let the *user* decide how many threads/cores he/she wants to use rather than trying to automatically figure it out some arbritray definition of "fair".

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not a problem of multithreading but a problem of executing many programs simultaneously. This is hard on most PC's operating systems because it conflicts to the idea of time-sharing.

Let's assume some workflow.

Suppose we have 8 cores and we create 8 threads to feed them; ok, that's easy.  Next we choose to monitor core loading to summary how many tasks running on a certain core; well, that needs some statistical assumptions, e.g on Linux you can get a 1/5/15-mins load average chart, but that could be done.  The statistical chart is clear and now we get a plot about how many CPU-bound processes are running, say, seeing other 3 CPU-intensive processes.

Then we come to the point: we have to make 3 redundant threads to sleep, but which 3?

Usually we choose 3 threads arbitrarily because the scheduler arranges the other 8 CPU-bound threads automatically.  In some cases, we explicitly put threads on high load cores to sleep, assign other threads to certain low load cores, and let the scheduler do the rest things.  Most scheduling policies also try to *"keep CPU cache hot"*, which means they tend to forbid transferring threads between cores.  We reasonably expect our CPU-intensive threads can utilize the core cache since other processes are scheduled to the 3 crowded cores.   Everything looks good.

However this could fail in tightly synchronized computation.  In this scenario we need to run our 5 threads simultaneously.  Simultaneity here means the 5 threads have to gain CPU and run at almost the same time.  I don't know if there's any scheduler on PC could do this for us.  In most low-load cases, things still work fine because costs to wait for simultaneity is trivial.  But when the load of a core is high and even 1 of our 5 threads is disturbed, occasionally we'll find we spend many life cycles in waiting.

It may help to schedule your program as a real-time program but it's not a perfect solution.  Statistically it leads to a wider time window for simultaneity when it gains more CPU control priority.  I have to say, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Agreed.  Right now I'm thinking that I could make my process unilaterally adaptive - that is, it dynamically adjusts the number of active threads up and down, trying to find the optimum number.  However, the risk here is that this might interfere with the scheduler's own feedback loops or with other running processes that dynamically adjust their CPU usage.  Result could be oscillation with multiple positive feedback loops.

Comment: Yes, too much synchronization harms the idea of parallel.  However, keep your threads dynamically serving is a viable approach but it may also cause more problems, like it cannot utilize CPUs in a good manner or it forms buggy fundamental..., etc.  To keep the design simple, perhaps you could try to code in kernel mode, being a driver module for computation.  I've once done that on Linux, very funny maintaining kernel threads.

Comment: Well, funny means many kernel crashes for the price of controlling scheduler with kernel kits. :-D